# How do I remove the title bar with tkinter on linux LXDE without overrideredirect or attributes?

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, raspberry-pi, window

[my previous post was closed stating it was a duplicate but I still do not have an answer]

I am trying to create a window without a title bar that has buttons on it. These buttons would open/run certain programs (open web browser, reboot computer, etc). I want this window to remain on the screen always and not able to be closed (like a kiosk with buttons on the screen).

On windows, I am able to make this work fine with overrideredirect(True) and attributes("-topmost", True). However, when I run the program on a raspberry pi with LXDE, it doesn't recognize the overrideredirect(True). I have tried changing True to 1 and still no success. I am unable to find anything about this for LXDE specifically. Is it not possible since my window manager is not responding to this argument? Maybe there is another way to accomplish what I am trying to do.

I also tried the `attributes('-type', 'splash')` and `attributes('-type', 'dock')` without success.

```
import tkinter as tk
import webbrowser

root = tk.Tk()

#URL to open when Browser button
browser_url = 'http://www.google.com'

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1, pady=20)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):           
        self.browser = tk.Button(self, height=2, width=10)
        self.browser["text"] = "Browser"
        self.browser["command"] = self.browser_go
        self.browser.pack(side="left", padx=25)

    def browser_go(self):
        webbrowser.open_new(browser_url)            

root.geometry('2160x100+0+0')       #Window size (x,y) and location (x,y)
root.resizable(False, False)        #Window not resizeable
root.update_idletasks()
root.overrideredirect(True)         #Prevent ability to close the windows
root.attributes("-topmost", True)   #Window on top always of other windows
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: do you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: No, I am not getting any error messages. It just will not remove the title bar with either of these options. I have read that x11 is needed to respond to these and my understanding is that is what LXDE uses as its window manager.

Comment: as I kno `X11` is used in all `Linux` as background service for `LXDE`, `GNOME`, and any other windows managers or environments. I tested code on Linux Mint with `Gnome` and it also doesn't work.

Comment: I can get borderless window only with `root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)` and without `root.resizable(False, False)` - but it use full screen and can't change its size

Comment: your code works for me if I remove `root.update_idletasks()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works for me on Linux Mint 19.2 with Gnome if I remove

```
root.update_idletasks()
```

or if I use it after `root.overrideredirect(True)`

Maybe it will works also for your system.

```
import tkinter as tk
import webbrowser

root = tk.Tk()

#URL to open when Browser button
browser_url = 'http://www.google.com'

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1, pady=20)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):           
        self.browser = tk.Button(self, height=2, width=10)
        self.browser["text"] = "Browser"
        self.browser["command"] = self.browser_go
        self.browser.pack(side="left", padx=25)

    def browser_go(self):
        webbrowser.open_new(browser_url)            

root.geometry('2160x100+0+0')       #Window size (x,y) and location (x,y)
root.resizable(False, False)        #Window not resizeable
root.overrideredirect(True)         #Prevent ability to close the windows

#root.update_idletasks() # has to be after root.overrideredirect(True)

root.attributes("-topmost", True)   #Window on top always of other windows
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

I don't need even `root.resizable(False, False)` and `root.attributes("-topmost", True)`

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('2160x100+0+0')       #Window size (x,y) and location (x,y)
root.overrideredirect(True)         #Prevent ability to close the windows
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hot dog! That did it!  I really really appreciate your help.  I just moved `root.update_idletasks()` and it worked.  I am still learning and appreciate the speedy help.